# How to change the appearance of superuser.com

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, html

I want to change the appearance of superuser.com site on my google chrome and increase the contrast, change font size etc.,. I do not want to use any plugin for changing the background color.

I came across this *"Inspect Element"* feature available in Chrome. I'd want to know if there are options (in its code) available to accomplish this ?

Edit: After using stylish for the first time - this is how it looks - but still unable to bring dark colors on superuser.com
[image]

Comment: Presumably you want these changes to persist the next time you visit this site?

Comment: Yes, everytime I visit this site - i want to changes to remain

Comment: I would guess that the easiest way would be a content script, without any extension this won't work.

Comment: what is a content script? - is it like a configuration in chrome?

Comment: You could ad the plugin Stylish and create something like this: https://userstyles.org/styles/97185/stack-overflow-dark-colors or https://userstyles.org/styles/109427/stackoverflow-style-fixer but then for other colors.

Comment: @Rik I used your first link to - it makes the stack overflow.com to contrast colours - but how should i apply that to superuser.com too?. I tried editing - but did not know where to locate the stackoverflow and replace with superuser

Comment: I added an answer to show you where you can change (or add) the URL to which this style applies.

Comment: It's funny - this was something you used to be able to do easily in all browsers; what happened?!

Comment: @w3d... I do not have a clue on how to do it... If there is an easy way - i would really like it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Stylish plugin to change colors on any website.
For dark-colors you can folow [this link](https://userstyles.org/styles/97185/stack-overflow-dark-colors).

When you installed Stylish and also installed the style in that link you can apply it to superuser.com by clicking on the Stylish-icon (upper right) and choosing `Manager installed styles`. Click the <kbd>Edit</kbd>-button (under `Stack Overflow Dark Colors`).

At the bottom click <kbd>Add</kbd> and type `superuser.com` in the URL-box.

[image]

Don't forget to click <kbd>Save</kbd> at the top-left to save the settings.
[image]

Of course you can also play with the colors in that Edit-screen.

---

**Edit:** (LOL)
I saw the style also changes the logo to the one from Stackoverflow. (But you really are on the Superuser-site). If you put a # before the background-image-line you can remove the logo-substitution. In that case the original logo is used (but the text Superuser is quite dark).

```
#hlogo a {
    #background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/zeNdkNx.png") !important;
    background-size: 280px;
    width:280px;
    height:90px;
}
```

[image]

Also if superuser.com is the only site you need this you can create your own logo (inversed) and use it in the script.

---

**Edit #2**:
If changing the ["Stack Overflow Dark Colors"](https://userstyles.org/styles/97185/stack-overflow-dark-colors) doesn't work for you, you could try ["stack overflow dark"](https://userstyles.org/styles/55155/stack-overflow-dark). That one has superuser.com already build in as included site.

Comment: Adding superuser.com to the list - does not work for me - unfortunately ;-(  What could be wrong?

Comment: @Prasanna That's strange. You did click save (after clicking Add and adding superuser.com)? I did it again here on my home-computer and it works here. Does it still work for stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Thats the thing. It works for stackoverflow.com  - By the way, I did click the  "SAVE" button after the modification

Comment: @Prasanna What happens if you reinstall the script and don't change anything in the script and **change** stackoverflow.com to superuser.com (in stead of adding it)? Does it work then?

Comment: @Prasanna I added an "Edit #2" with another userstyle which already had `superuser.com` build in. It's [here](https://userstyles.org/styles/55155/stack-overflow-dark). Does that one work for you?? I also saw you had "everything" but that was for the upper section. You didn't show your addition of `superuser.com` **below** the css-style changes. It's all the way at the bottom. [Like this](http://i.imgur.com/ylHbxbe.png) (adding `superuser.com` there).

Comment: Just FYI, Stylish appears to be incompatible with the SE-auto-comments add-in, at least in Firefox (or perhaps it's just specific skins).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `URLs maching the regexp` instead 'URL on the domain'.

And value of it needs to be `^https?://((chat|meta).)?superuser.com.*`

[image]